# How to develop a recursive CTE in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I am new to recursive CTEs. I am trying to develop a CTE which will return all of the employees under each manager name. So I have two tables: `people_rv` and `staff_rv`

People_rv table contains all of the people, both managers and employees. `Staff_rv` only contains manager information.  Uniqueidentifier staff values are stored in `Staff_rv`.  Uniqueidentifier employee values are stored in `people_rv`.  `People_rv` contains varchar first and last name values for both managers and employees.

But when I run the following CTE I get an error:

```
WITH
cteStaff (ClientID, FirstName, LastName, SupervisorID, EmpLevel)
AS
(
    SELECT p.people_id, p.first_name, p.last_name, s.supervisor_id,1
    FROM people_rv p JOIN staff_rv s on s.people_id = p.people_id
    WHERE s.supervisor_id = '95E16819-8C3A-4098-9430-08F0E3B764E1' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT p2.people_id, p2.first_name, p2.last_name, s2.supervisor_id, r.EmpLevel + 1
    FROM people_rv p2 JOIN staff_rv s2 on s2.people_id = p2.people_id
    INNER JOIN cteStaff r on s2.staff_id = r.ClientID
)
SELECT
    FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS FullName, 
    EmpLevel,
    (SELECT first_name + ' ' + last_name FROM people_rv p join staff_rv s on s.people_id = p.people_id 
    WHERE s.staff_id = cteStaff.SupervisorID) AS Manager
FROM cteStaff
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

My output is:

```
Barbara G   1   Melanie K
Dawn P  1   Melanie K
Garrett M   1   Melanie K
Stephanie P 1   Melanie K
Amanda F    1   Melanie K
Amanda T    1   Melanie K
Stephanie G 1   Melanie K
Carlos H    1   Melanie K
```

So it is not iterating any more than the first level.  Why not?
Melanie is the top most supervisor, but each of the persons in the leftmost column are also supervisors.  So this query should also return level 2.

Comment: Are you sure the GUID used in the terminating leg of the recursive CTE is correct? first thing I'm thinking of is that the recursive portion is never terminating, and the first notion that comes to mind is that the terminating condition is never met...and that GUID seems at least a likely target...

Comment: Potential typo: in the INNER JOIN, does your query now use `s2.staff_ID` where it appears to need `s2.supervisor_id` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be in an infinite loop with your join.  I would check how many levels you expect the table to actually go down.  Generally you join a recursion on something similar to do

```
 ID = ParentID
```

of something either contained in a table or in an expression.  Keep in mind you can also create a CTE prior to a recursive CTE if you have to make up your relationship.

Here is an example that will self execute, it may help.

```
Declare @table table ( PersonId int identity, PersonName varchar(512), Account int, ParentId int, Orders int);

insert into @Table values ('Brett', 1, NULL, 1000),('John', 1, 1, 100),('James', 1, 1, 200),('Beth', 1, 2, 300),('John2', 2, 4, 400);

select 
    PersonID
,   PersonName
,   Account
,   ParentID
from @Table

; with recursion as 
    (
    select 
        t1.PersonID
    ,   t1.PersonName
    ,   t1.Account
    --, t1.ParentID
    ,   cast(isnull(t2.PersonName, '')
            + Case when t2.PersonName is not null then '\' + t1.PersonName else t1.PersonName end
            as varchar(255)) as fullheirarchy
    ,   1 as pos
    ,   cast(t1.orders + 
            isnull(t2.orders,0) -- if the parent has no orders than zero
            as int) as Orders
    from @Table t1
        left join @Table t2 on t1.ParentId = t2.PersonId
    union all
    select 
        t.PersonID
    ,   t.PersonName
    ,   t.Account
    --, t.ParentID
    ,   cast(r.fullheirarchy + '\' + t.PersonName as varchar(255))
    ,   pos + 1  -- increases
    ,   r.orders + t.orders
    from @Table t
        join recursion r on t.ParentId = r.PersonId
    )
, b as 
    (
    select *, max(pos) over(partition by PersonID) as maxrec  -- I find the maximum occurrence of position by person
    from recursion
    )
select *
from b
where pos = maxrec  -- finds the furthest down tree
-- and Account = 2  -- I could find just someone from a different department
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem as far as I can tell is is you have no join connecting managers to their employees.

This join

```
INNER JOIN cteStaff r on r.StaffID = s2.staff_id
```

Just joins the same initial level 1 staffer back to himself.

UPDATE:

Still not quite right! You have a supervisor_id, but again you're still not actually using that to join back to the CTE.

So for each recursion of this CTE you need to (excluding the name join):

```
select {Level 1 Boss}, NULL (no supervisor)
union
select {new employee}, {that employee's boss}
```

So the join must connect the CTE's ClientID (the level 1 boss) to the second UNION query's **supervisor** field, which looks to be **supervisor_id** , not **staff_id**.

The JOIN to accomplish this second task is (from what I can tell of your staff_rv table schema):

```
 SELECT p2.people_id, p2.first_name, p2.last_name, s2.supervisor_id, r.EmpLevel + 1
    FROM people_rv p2 JOIN staff_rv s2 on s2.people_id = p2.people_id
    INNER JOIN cteStaff r on s2.supervisor_id = r.ClientID
```

Note the bottom join joins the r.ClientID (the level 1 boss) to the staffer's supervisor_id field.

(NB: I think your staff_id and supervisor_id's mimic your people_id values from the people_rv table, so this join should work fine. But if they are different (i.e. a staffer's supervisor_id isn't that supervisor's people_id) then you'll need to write the join such that the staffer's supervisor_id can be joined to their people_id you're storing as ClientID in the CTE.)

Comment: Great point, Kyle!  I modified my query above and have tried many variations on this, but it's not giving me deeper than one level.  Can you identify where it is wrong?

Comment: I updated my answer. Your union join looks a little off based on my understanding of your schema ...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good simple Recursive CTE to review (it may not be the answer, but someone else searching on how to make a recursive CTE may need it):

```
-- Recursive CTE
;
WITH    Years ( myYear )
          AS (
               -- Base case
      SELECT    DATEPART(year, GETDATE())
               UNION ALL
      -- Recursive
               SELECT   Years.myYear - 1
               FROM     Years
               WHERE    Years.myYear >= 2002
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    Years
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that this probably won't solve your problem, but is a means to hopefully seeing where you're going wrong in the original query.

The default is 100 levels of recursion - you can set it to unlimited by using the `MAXRECURSION` query hint where you're selecting from your CTE:

```
...
FROM cteStaff
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms181714.aspx):

> MAXRECURSION number
>
> Specifies the maximum number of recursions allowed for this query. number is a nonnegative integer between 0 and 32767. When 0 is
>   specified, no limit is applied. If this option is not specified, the
>   default limit for the server is 100.
>
> When the specified or default number for MAXRECURSION limit is reached during query execution, the query is ended and an error is
>   returned.
>
> Because of this error, all effects of the statement are rolled back. If the statement is a SELECT statement, partial results or no
>   results may be returned. Any partial results returned may not include
>   all rows on recursion levels beyond the specified maximum recursion
>   level.

Comment: This is technically accurate, but that's not the underlying issue, unless there are really 101+ employee levels in his table. (Do you work at Initech?)

Comment: @KyleHale I just wanted to tell OP about the hint - I don't have a SQL Server box in front of me to test the query ;-)

Comment: I just updated my description.  Could you have a look please?

Comment: I've updated my answer to point out that it's more of a general solution than will actually solve his problem in this instance.